# Are shimano FH-2200 hubs strong enough to use in a tubular wheel for CX racing?

Tags: wheels, hub, cyclocross, wheel-building

I have a pair of Shimano FH-2200 front and rear hubs lying around which I no longer use and I would like to save money by using them for a wheel build but am unsure whether they would be up to the rigors of Cyclocross racing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I would suspect they are just fine. These are relatively inexpensive when new, and require little maintenance if broken down and lubed once in a while.

What really matters in cyclocross is the number of spoke holes and flange geometry of the hub. I just did a quick google and found FH-2200 hubs have beefy flanges and 36 spoke holes. I was not able to find any other configuration.

I've more often than not found wheel failures at the spoke junctions (hub, rim) or the rim itself. I've very rarely seen a hub fail that has been properly maintained.

So, my answer is this: they should be fine. Lace them up in a 3x pattern with a decent rim and enjoy some cyclocross!

Comment: Another issue with hub strength is the lacing pattern.  Radial lacing places serious strains on the flanges and can cause them to fail, whereas it's just about impossible for a flange to fail if laced 3x.